# Testing Form Requests with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, rest

I am trying to test various API endpoints with Laravel but keep getting back 302 redirects.

```php
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(RegisterRequest $request) {
        
    }
}
```

```php
class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return !request()->user();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username'  =>  'required|min:3',
            'password'  =>  'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' =>  'required|min:6'
        ];
    }
}
```

And my test case

```php
class RegisterTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testRegisterFailsWithNoFields()
    {
        $res = $this->post('/api/register');

        $res->assertStatus(422);
    }
}
```

It's pretty straightforward, I am expecting a response back with errors but instead am met with a 302 redirect which sends me back to / which isn't great for API's. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close, and it's a tiny mistake/misconception about your test request.

`$this->post()` sends a regular ol' `POST` request with no `Accept` header and so you are getting a 302 response as Laravel is trying to redirect you back with your errors in the session.

Try `$this->postJson()` instead.

Comment: Wow, just wow, can't believe I missed this, I always remember testing with just `post()` maybe my memory is off, I really need to get into testing more. thanks! Will accept the answer asap (in 10 min)